# What is the equivalent of the following Python list comprehension in Fortran?

Tags: python, fortran, list-comprehension, fortran90

I am trying to write the following list comprehension(written in Python) in Fortran.

```
lit = [[x,y] for x in [p,q,r] for y in [h,k,l] if [x,y]!=[a,b]]
```

where
`a, b, p ,q ,r, h, k, l` are integers

How can I achieve it if I want to fill columns first in 2D Fortran array?

The Python code returns a list. It is equivalent to

```
for x in [p,q,r]:
     for y in [h,k,l]:
         if [x,y]!=[a,b]:
             list.append([x,y])
```

I made two sublists in Fortran. `sublist_x` and `sublist_y` where each list contains `p,q,r` and `h,k,l` respectively.

```
integer :: list(0:7), sublist_x(0:2),sublist_y(0:2), count
 count =-1

do i=0,7
   if (i%3 ==0)
   count = count +1
   endif
   list(0,i)=sublist_x(i%3)
   list(1,i)=sublist_y(count%3)
enddo
```

I think this is a complex way of doing things...

Comment: Just added edits. 

Plus, would using fortran90 or fortran matter much?

Comment: You should **always** use the generic tag for the language ([tag:fortran], [tag:python] ). Add any more specific tags **only** if you need to make clear that you are restricting yourself just to that version. Fortran 90 is old, we have year 2015, the current standard is Fortran 2008, Fortran 2015 is coming. Python 2.7 is also quite old.

Comment: all my code is in python2.7... It would take a great deal of pain to move to latest python version. :\

Since some of it could be written in fortran (matrix handling and lot of numerical computation) I thought to give it a try.

*I am lazy to port python to latest version.*

Comment: @VladimirF : Thanks. Will keep in mind. :D

Comment: That doesn't matter, it is still Python. The code you shown still conforms to the latest standard of the Python language, there is absolutely no reason to speak about 2.7 specifically here.

Comment: there are several things wrong with your code, but for starters you should have nested loops (over x and over y). Everything in the loop should be inside the `if` block. Also to exactly replicate the python you need to first determine the size of the resulting list (which depends on the `if` construct ) and allocate it to the proper dimension.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want the cartesian product of the two little lists, excluding the element `[a,b]` ?  If I misunderstand, stop reading now.  Here's a little program that almost does what you want ...

```
PROGRAM test

  IMPLICIT NONE

  INTEGER, DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: listx, listy, bad_element
  INTEGER, DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: outlist
  INTEGER :: ix, jx, alstat, n_elements

  LOGICAL, DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: rows

  listx = [1,2,3]
  listy = [21,22,23]
  bad_element = [3,21]

  n_elements = SIZE(listx)*SIZE(listy)
  ALLOCATE(outlist(2,n_elements),stat=alstat)
  IF (alstat/=0) THEN
     WRITE(*,*) "something went wrong allocating the result array"
     STOP
  ELSE
     outlist(1,:) = RESHAPE(listx,[n_elements],listx)
     outlist(2,:) = RESHAPE(SPREAD(listy,1,SIZE(listx)),[n_elements])
  END IF

  DO ix = 1, n_elements
     IF (ALL(outlist(:,ix)==bad_element)) THEN
        outlist(:,ix:) = EOSHIFT(outlist(:,ix:),1,dim=2)
     END IF
  END DO

END PROGRAM TEST
```

At the end of this program `outlist` contains the cartesian product with any elements equal to the bad element replaced by `0`s and pushed to the end of `outlets`.  For the hard-wired numbers above, the output is:

```
    1    2    1    2    3    1    2    3    0
   21   21   22   22   22   23   23   23    0
```

I guess you shouldn't have too much difficulty trimming this to remove the `0`s, nor in packaging this program into a routine.  And I hope the code explains itself.

Comment: I love the smell of Fortran in the morning.

Comment: Thanks. I needed this only. :) is there a way to do this with less time complexity? I'll need to call this function thousands of times.

Comment: Would you suggest using fortran90 or later? That makes a lot of difference?

Comment: *Would you suggest using fortran90 or later?*  I'd suggest using whatever your compiler supports.

Comment: *is there a way to do this with less time complexity?*  Possibly.  What ideas do you have ?